# PowerShell using user attributes to assign to another user attribute

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I was creating what I thought was a super-simple PowerShell script to update the location field with "Mobile: " + Mobile Phone number.  Using the limited fields on GAL to show mobile number for all users.

Somehow, I only get the "Mobile: " without the number.  I have tried many variations of this same script but ultimately $User.mobile is incorrect.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Userlist = Get-ADUser -Server XXXXX -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Corporate,OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com"
foreach ($User in $Userlist) {
    $newlocation = "Mobile: "
    $newlocation = $newlocation + $User.mobile
    Set-ADUser -Instance $User
}

# Update properties.
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think that $newLocation would in any way be connected to the properties on $user?

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted from powershell and missed some lines.  There was a  $user. physicaldeliveryofficename = $newlocation, before the Set-AdUser

Comment: @UMBCDeveloper Please update your question with your actual code. We're not going to piece together what your code might look like from comments. Don't fabricate things, don't type from memory. Copy and paste a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to change here:

Include the `mobile` and `location` attributes in the original `Get-ADUser` query, it won't retrieve these by default:

```
$Userlist = Get-ADUser -Server XXXXX -filter * -Properties mobile,physicalDeliveryOfficeName -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Corporate,OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com"
```

and then make sure you actually *modify* the `$User` object before calling `Set-ADUser`:

```
foreach ($User in $Userlist) {
    $newlocation = "Mobile: " + $User.mobile
    $User.physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $newlocation
    Set-ADUser -Instance $User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Get-AdUser adding -properties was the answer.  It worked like a charm.

$Userlist = Get-ADUser -Server XXXXX -filter * **-Properties mobile,physicalDeliveryOfficeName** -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Corporate,OU=XXXXXXXX,DC=XXXXXX,DC=com"

foreach($User in $userlist)

```
{
    $newlocation = "Mobile: " + $User.mobile
    $User.physicalDeliveryOfficeName = $newlocation
    Set-ADUser -Instance $User
}
```